# No bigodd nonsense

Tags: phrases, history

I am writing a novel with a narrator who is (supposedly) writing in 1854-5. One of his characters refers to someone who is "a plain Englishman with no bigodd nonsense about him." As is well known, Charles Dickens puts this phrase into the mouth of Edmund Sparkler in "Little Dorrit" (usually with reference to his mother or his wife). The chapter of "Little Dorrit" where the phrase is first used was published in 1855. If Dickens invented the phrase, then my narrator would be directly quoting a fashionable (serialised) novel; if Dickens did not invent the phase, then there is no quotation (or half-quotation). This point is of some (though not of crucial) significance in my novel.

Does anybody know any earlier use of phrase, perhaps with a different spelling of "bigodd"?

Comment: I can't find the word bigodd at all.

Comment: Dickens may well have had in mind the phrase "no damned nonsense about him" which was and is common, but obviously cannot be set down in print. (My apologies to any well-brought-up ladies who swooned on reading this comment).

Comment: None found, probably a euphemism for "by god"

Comment: Your definition of _well-known_ clearly differs somewhat from mine.

Comment: @J. Taylor: either that, or a phonetic spelling of "by god". (I wouldn't be surprised if this was an idiom where the words were commonly slurred together.)

Comment: @ChrisM - I found it at Gutenberg and fullbooks.com.

Comment: The actual text in Little Dorrit is "Being a remarkably fine woman with no bigodd nonsense about her..."